# Funções em Python-Variáveis globais e locais

Tags: python

Tem como deixar com que a variável de dentro de uma função (local) fique global? Se não, qual a forma que nós podemos declarar uma variável global?

Comment: Você declara a variável fora da função e dentro da função você declara `global` na frente da variável. Entretanto o uso de variáveis globais não é aconselhado em grandes projetos por se tornar perigoso sua modificação acidental.

Comment: E porque você faria isso? Gambiarra da grossa, monte algo melhor que não precise disto.

Answer (score 2):

Tem, retornando ela.

Existem escopos definidos e "rígidos" assim porque é o melhor ambiente - ou pelo menos facilita muito a vida do desenvolvedor, pois quanto menor seu escopo, mais fácil é gerenciar suas variáveis. Ter funções que alteram o escopo global são péssimas para manutenção, prejudicam muito a legibilidade do código e geraram muitos *WTF* no seu projeto (com certeza há muitas outras implicações).

Mas não é um caso perdido. Assim como você, muitas outras pessoas antes já sentiram a necessidade de retornar para o escopo externo algumas variáveis definidas no escopo externo. Disso surgiu o `return` - talvez não exatamente assim, mas por hora é uma historinha bonitinha.

Ou seja, se você define `foo` dentro da função e quer exportá-la para o escopo exterior, basta retornar `foo`:

```
def minhaFuncaoQueNaoFazMagica():
    foo = 'qualquer coisa'
    ...
    return foo
```

Desta forma, no escopo exterior, bastaria fazer:

```
foo = minhaFuncaoQueNaoFazMagica()
```

Ficando explícito como `foo` surgiu neste escopo, sem mágicas *gambiarísticas*.

Mas aí você me pergunta: Anderson, mas e seu precisar retornar várias variáveis da função? A resposta é simples: refatore. Ter esta necessidade é um indício claro que a maneira que está fazendo não é a mais simples e você precisa refazer. Se necessita retornar várias variáveis, elas estarão, de alguma forma, relacionadas entre si e, provavelmente, seriam melhor organizadas dentro de uma classe/objeto. Mas e se elas não tiverem relação nenhuma entre si, a classe não ficaria esquisita? Sim, mas se não há relação entre as variáveis, elas não deveriam estar na mesma função.

Assim como tudo na natureza, você deve buscar no seu código o estado de menor energia. Não basta só funcionar, precisa funcionar e não gerar problemas no futuro. Quanto menos você ter que voltar para dar manutenção nesse trecho de código, melhor, então faça algo consistente.

Comment: Desculpe - bastante texto, e muita explicação, mas está simplesmente errado. Existe a palavra chave "global".

Answer (score 2):

Sim - 
Basta declarar a variável como global no início da função:

```
def a():
   global b
   b = "teste"

a()
print(b)
```

(imprime "teste")

A palavra chave `nonlocal` pode ser usada em funções declaradas dentro de outras funções (aninhadas), e, de forma parecida, permite o acesso e alteração de variáveis em funções, "exteriores" - mas não pode ser usada da mesma forma que `global` para declarar uma variável que não existe no escopo da função exterior, já que pode haver mais de uma função exterior,  e "onde" criar a variável seria ambíguo:

```
In [40]: def a():
    ...:     def b():
    ...:         nonlocal c
  File "<ipython-input-40-dbf568c371f7>", line 3
    nonlocal c
    ^
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'c' found
```

Também é interessante notar que há uma cultura muito grande de que "variáveis globais são ruins" e "são gambiarra" - mas esse não é o caso em Python - e já esclareço isso.

Antes no entanto, vale ressaltar que se você for usar uma variável global, é prática, sim, declara-la *fora* das funções, no começo do arquivo, para que seja visível. O uso da palavra chave `global` nas funções permite que ela seja alterada do mesmo jeito do que se for declara pela primeira vez em uma função - mas isso evita surpresas da variável aparecer "do nada" pra quem estiver revisando o código.

Por fim - em Python elas não são tão ruins, como acontece em algumas linguagens e de onde vem o discurso de "não use", por que Python usa namespaces de forma bem sistemática e transparente - assim, uma variável nunca é "global" com um nome único em toda a aplicação - ela é "global" só no módulo onde foi declarada (via de regra, um módulo corresponde a um único arquivo ".py").

Por exemplo, os proprios valores "pi" e "e" da matemática são "variáveis globais" no módulo "math". Num programa em C usando varios arquivos fonte, isso faria com que em qualquer arquivo, você pudesse de repente usar "e" como uma variável contendo a constante, tirando isso do "nada" - e isso é o que torna a manutenção de variáveis globais complicada - e cria essa cultura de "variável global não deve ser usada". Mas em Python, se você quiser usar o "e", tem que explicitar no começo de cada arquivo em que vai usa-la: `from math import e`, ou simplesmente `import math` e usar `math.e` naquele arquivo.

Mais que isso, em Python, não temos propriamente "variáveis",e mais tecnicamente "nomes" associados a objetos. Nesse sentido, os "nomes" são definidos pelo *comando* `=`  que é o que lemos como uma "declaração de variável", mas também são definidos pelos comandos `def` quando declaramos uma função, `class`, quando declaramos uma classe, etc... Ou seja: **em Python todas as funções e classes declaradas em um módulo são, também, "variáveis globais".**

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação, vou ver se irá encaixar no meu código... Agora vou explicar o por quê dessa "gambiarra"...  Estou fazendo um mini sistema de cadastro utilizando apenas o pyhton como linguagem (eu sei que é errado, mas ainda estou meio sem tempo para estudar outras) Meu sistema até agora tem uma interface usando o módulo tkinter e tem um banco de dados, fazendo a conexão com o SqLite3... Mas estou tendo que fazer várias gambiarras, pois a tela que recolhe os dados está numa função.

Comment: Nessa mesma função tem um botão que quando clicado, chama outra função, que é a que vai transportar esses dados para o banco de dados, mas como os dados estão dentro da função janela() eles estão como variáveis locais (eu acho), só sei que na hora de recolher os dados, o shell fala que a variável não foi definida, logo pensei que estava ocorrendo isso ao fato de ela estar em uma função e o transporte dela estar em outra função. Resultado: Estou quebrando muito a cabeça pra fazer um sistema usando gambiarras e uma linguagem... Vou ver se dou um jeito nisso, Desistir é a ultima opção..

Comment: Variáveis globais é com "global". O problema que você está descrevendo provavelmente fica melhor com atributos em um objeto. Faça uma outra pergunta, descrevendo o seu problema, não o que você acha que é a solução, e ponha o seu código - aí as pessoas podem te orientar num bom design para o código. Do jeito que está, estão elocubrando complicações desncessárias por causa do jeito que a pergunta foi feita (em vez de dizer como declarar variaveis globais, o que é trivial, pensando em formas de "promover" uma variável local para global, o que é malabarismo com pouca utilidade real.)

Answer (score -1):

Em `Python`, as variáveis declaradas dentro de funções são tratadas como atributos dentro de objetos, e esses atributos podem ser acessados a partir do escopo global usando o nome do objeto/função que a contém como referência.

Caso você queira que o escopo global tenha acesso as variáveis declaradas dentro de funções, basta prefixar a variável com o nome da função ao declara-la e ao acessá-la, veja só:

```
def foobar():
    foobar.n = 123 

foobar() # Funcao declara e inicializa a variavel 'n'

print(foobar.n) #Lendo 'n' em foobar()

foobar.n = 456  #Alterando 'n' em foobar()

print(foobar.n) #Lendo 'n' em foobar()
```

Saída:

```
123
456
```

Há casos no qual a função que declara a variável ainda não foi chamada, e consequentemente, tal variável ainda não foi declarada:

```
def foobar():
    foobar.n = 123

print(foobar.n) # AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'n'
```

Para saber se a variável já foi declarada no escopo da função, basta testá-la por meio da função nativa [`hasattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr), veja só:

```
def foobar():
    foobar.n = 123 

# ...    

if not hasattr(foobar, "n"):
    print("variavel nao declarada!")
else
    print(foobar.n)
```

Comment: Resposta extensa, com coisas legais, mas errada. Desculpa , -1.

Comment: Errada em que sentido? Poderia explicar? Eu não vivo só de elogios.

Comment: sim - está errada por que a palavra chave "global" faz exatamente o que está sendo perguntado, e você nem menciona isso na resposta.

Comment: Além disso, a solução que você apresenta de usar a própria função como namespace é engenhosa, mas não é uma prática comum - se fosse em um code review, eu sugeriria usar uma classe e colocar esse "atributo da função" como um atributo da instância.

Comment: Foi de propósito que eu evitei usar a palavra `global` na minha resposta: Quando você usa a palavra `global` dentro de uma função, a variável afetada se torna parte *única e somente* do escopo global e não mais pertence exclusivamente do escopo da função. A prova disso é que `foobar.n` pode coesistir com `n` (no escopo global), ou seja, em espaços diferentes de memória. A pergunta dá a entender que é o escopo de fora (global) que está com o intento de acessar as variáveis declaradas dentro do escopo da função. Foram a partir dessas premissas que eu elaborei a minha resposta. Obrg pelo retorno.

Comment: Entendi o seu raciocínio agora. Mas sem nem sequer mecionar `global` na sua resposta, que é o "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." para variáveis globais em Python - e o que outras pessoas vão querer saber quando cairem aqui com dúvida, eu pessoalmente não considero que a resposta esteja correta.

Comment: (parábéns pelos 10K, aliás!)