# name ' ' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def notas():
    opcao = 0
    while opcao != 5:
        n1 = int(input("Digite sua nota 1 :"))
        n2 = int(input("Digite sua nota 2 :"))
        n3 = int(input("Digite sua nota 3 :"))
        opcao = input("Deseja sair?")
        return opcao

def media():
    medias = (n1+n2+n3) / 3
    print(" Sua media é {}",media)

notas()
media()
```

Sou iniciante em Python, e gostaria de saber porque está retornando este erro?

Answer (score 2):

Você esta retornando a variável errada, o certo seria você armazenar as variáveis n1, n2, n3 dentro de uma lista e retornar essa lista, e depois passar essa lista como parâmetro na segunda função.

```
def notas():
    opcao = 0
    # Aqui é criado a lista
    variaveis = []
    while opcao != 5:
        n1 = int(input("Digite sua nota 1 :"))
        n2 = int(input("Digite sua nota 2 :"))
        n3 = int(input("Digite sua nota 3 :"))
        variaveis.append(n1)
        variaveis.append(n2)
        variaveis.append(n3)
        opcao = input("Deseja sair? (Digite 5 para sair)")
    # Retornando a lista
    return variaveis

def media(variaveis):
    medias = (variaveis[0]+variaveis[1]+variaveis[2]) / 3
    print(f" Sua media é {medias}")

# Salvando o valor retornado
n = notas()
media(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, está retornando o erro de  `name ' ' is not defined`, pois as variáveis não foram definidas na função `media()`

Observe que você definiu as variáveis `n1`, `n2`, `n3` e `opcao` **no corpo da função `notas()`**, ou seja, elas estão com o escopo local e portanto a função `media()` não as '**enxerga**'

Uma maneira de resolver isto seria definir as variáveis como **global**:

```
def notas():
    global n1,n2,n3 
    opcao = 0
    while opcao != 5:
         n1 = int(input("Digite sua nota 1 :"))
         n2 = int(input("Digite sua nota 2 :"))
         n3 = int(input("Digite sua nota 3 :"))
         opcao = input("Deseja sair?")
         return opcao

def media():
    media = (n1+n2+n3) / 3
    print(" Sua media é {}",media)

notas()
media()
```

Obs.: Não fiz nenhuma melhoria no seu código, mas há possibilidade de fazer várias!

Pelo fato de você ser iniciante em Python, aconselho estudar as seguintes perguntas:

Para entender o que é escopo em Python:

[Como é identificado um bloco de escopo em uma linguagem como Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135724/como-%C3%A9-identificado-um-bloco-de-escopo-em-uma-linguagem-como-python)

Para entender o conceito de global em Python:

[Funções em Python-Variáveis globais e locais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/312440/fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-python-vari%C3%A1veis-globais-e-locais?noredirect=1)

[Qual a diferença de global e nonlocal no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250362/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-global-e-nonlocal-no-python)